# Error when trying to inherit from class with constructor in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm having trouble with my code.The student class defines the strings studName and studRegNum as protected data members. I have created a constructor that has arguments to initialize the data members. The class studentAthlete inherits from student and has a private data member sport, which describes the sport the student plays. Both classes have a member function identify() which outputs student information.

When I run the code I get the error message "no matching function for call to 'student::student()'  "

Please help. Im new to C++
Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
protected:
    string studName;
    string studRegNum;
public:
    //Constructor prototype
    student(string name, string regNo);
    void identify();
};
//Constructor for student class
student::student(string name, string regNo):
studName(name), studRegNum(regNo)
{

}
class studentAthlete : public student
{
private:
    string member_sport;
    string get_member_sport(string member_Sport);
public:
    void identify();
    studentAthlete(string Sport);
};
studentAthlete::studentAthlete(string Sport):
member_sport(Sport)
{
}
string studentAthlete::get_member_sport(string member_Sport)
{
    member_Sport=member_sport;
    return member_sport;
}

void studentAthlete::identify()
{
    cout<<"Student Name: "<<studName<<endl;
    cout<<"Student Registration Number: "<<studRegNum<<endl;
    cout<<"Student sport: "<<member_sport<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    string studentName, registrationNO, studentSport;//Variables that will hold student information
    cout<<"Enter Student name: "<<endl;
    cin>>studentName;
    cout<<"Enter Registration number: "<<endl;
    cin>>registrationNO;
    cout<<"Enter Student Sport: "<<endl;
    cin>>studentSport;
    student st(studentName,registrationNO);
    studentAthlete sa(studentSport);
    cout<<"Student Details: ";sa.identify();

}
```

Comment: Why didn't you write a constructor for `studentAthlete `?

Comment: The instantiation of `studentAthlete` class object with `studentAthlete sa;` tries to call its base class' default constructor which doesn't exist.

Comment: you don't have default constructor in student

Comment: @vik_78 I am quite new to C++. How do I create default constructor in student?

Comment: You didn't write `studentAthlete` constructor -> default is generated -> it calls default constructor of base class -> you implemented your own constructor in `student` == there is no more "default, without parameters" constructor there -> error

Comment: If you want the default constructor back that was implicitly deleted when you added your own, add `Student() = default;` to your class.

Comment: You could give some default parameters to your constructor of Student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined a constructor in `student`, which takes two arguments. It has no default ('no argument') constructor because you defined one.

`studentAthlete`. doesn't have a constructor. So when you create a `studentAthlete`, it cannot construct its base class. There are two easy solutions:

- Create a no argument constructor in `student`
- Create a constructor in `studentAthelete` that calls the constructor you defined in `student`

Comment: To do bullet point 2, you need to know about the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone I am still getting the same error even after editing the code with a constructor for studentAthelete

Comment: Could you post your updated code @KalisploitTutorials? If you made your studentAthelete you have to ensure it will call the constructor in `student` - see the comment by user4581301